# как перемещать текст по странице сайта?

Tags: html, css, текст

У меня есть текст, а как мне его перемещать ВНИЗ/ВВЕРХ, ВПРАВО/ВЛЕВО ?

Comment: Надо его перемещать все время или в связис каким-то событием типа наведения мыши и т.п.?

Comment: нет, это обычный h1.
Я хочу узнать какие есть методы чтобы переместить его

Comment: Всмысле поместить изначально? (например внизу справа)

Comment: Даа,  заголовок поставить в нужное место в которое мне надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть в HTML файле у тебя есть:
`<h1 id='main'>Заголовок</h1>`
Тогда в css-файле нужно указать с помощью margin и padding:

```css
#main{
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:10px;
margin:12px
}
```

Comment: Ооо. То что надо

Comment: @Andryxa рад что помог, можете отметить ответ полезным, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Элемент можно двигать с помощью `transform: translate(...)`:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(-1em, 2em);
}
```

```html
как перемещать <span>текст</span> по странице сайта?
```

Answer (score 0):

Кинь текст в блок, потом для блока можешь сделать отступы с помощью margin и padding